# countable additivity for an outer measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu^*$ be an outer measure on an non-empty set $X$. Let $(E_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of pairwise disjoint $\mu^*-$measurable subsets of $X$. Let $B_n\subset E_n$ be arbitrary(not necessarily measurable), show that

$$\mu^*\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu^*(B_n)$$

Intuitively I see that these $B_n$'s are positively separated, however $\mu^*$ is not assumed to be a metric outer measure. How can we solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** It suffices to show

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \mu^\ast(B_n) \leqslant \mu^\ast\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n\right)$$

for all $N$. To see that, consider

$$A_N = \bigcup_{n=1}^N B_n$$

and use the measurability of the $E_n$ to conclude

$$\mu^\ast (A_N) = \sum_{n=1}^N \mu^\ast(B_n).$$

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. How does $A_N$ help in the proof? $B_n$ is not supposed to be measurable and so is $A_N$.Could you please give more details? Thank you

Comment: $$A_N\subset\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n,$$ so by the monotonicity of $\mu^\ast$, its outer measure is at most that of the union. By the measurability of the $E_n$ (Caratheodory criterion) and induction, you have the last equality.

Comment: This makes sense. I think I can figure this out with this. Thanks for the hint

Comment: Good. If you get stuck, you are welcome to ask for a further hint.